# How to add 2 components with drag and drop in the same tab horizontally?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-tabset

For a potential task, they wanted to create a lightning page with two sections where two components could be added, one on the left side and the other on the right side, all within the same tab. For example:

[image]

Tabs are straightforward to implement using the standard "tabs" component, but the issue is that for this tab, components can only be added vertically as shown in the following picture:

[image]

As seen in the previous picture, components can only be added vertically, but we need to add other components horizontally.
Is there any other way to make this without using code?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that isn't possible currently. However I've had the same request a few times before, so I've raised an idea here to try and get it prioritised:

[Multiple Columns within Tabs in Lightning App Builder](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000PJ3WhUAL/multiple-columns-within-tabs-in-lightning-app-builder)